# PublishedAdView makes Scrollview lagg

Tags: android, admob, scrollview, android-scrollview, adview

I created some `PublishedAdView` inside Scrollview with code shown below

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ads_AnchorsAds"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!--Some code -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <!-- some code -->


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_image">

                        <!-- some code -->

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/content_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
                                android:id="@+id/ads_TopMediumRectangle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
                                app:adUnitId="@string/ads_TopMediumRectangle" />


                            <!-- Some Code -->

                            <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
                                android:id="@+id/ads_InsideMediumRectangle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                app:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
                                app:adUnitId="@string/ads_InsideMediumRectangle" />


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Everything work fine, but these PublishedAdView make my scrollview performance so slow . I load this ads in `onCreate` of Activity by normal way in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherAdView). Is there a way to overcome it? i'm out of ideas. this is how my activity looks like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DesignUtil.configureNoAppBarTheme(ReadActivity.this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

mPublisherAdViewInside = findViewById(R.id.ads_InsideMediumRectangle);
        mPublisherAdViewInside.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
        mPublisherAdViewInside.setAdListener(new TribunAdListener(mPublisherAdViewInside));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this fixes your issue. But I would recommend refactoring the ScrollView, to have just 1 child, and the Ads in it.
You have a lot of useless linear and relative layouts in there, that are nested and might cause performance issues.

In a talk at Google I/O 2013 (Writing Custom Views for Android), Romain Guy clarified the misunderstanding that caused everyone to start using RelativeLayouts for everything. A RelativeLayout always has to do two measure passes. Overall it is negligible as long as your view hierarchy is simple. But if your hierarchy is complex, doing an extra measure pass could potentially be fairly costly. Also if you nest RelativeLayouts, you get an exponential measurement algorithm.

See if that helps, and try for now just with 1 Addview, and debug using the Android Profiler:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

This might help you figure out what is wrong.

Another options, I would recommend, if not, to use a RecyclerView, with multiple types of views, instead of a scrollview.

Using something like this in your RecyclerView:

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        when (viewType) {
            0 -> {
                val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.call_list_item, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder(itemView)
            }
            else -> {
                val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.call_list_item, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder(itemView)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually there are bunch of code inside every RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc (Which i noted as 'Some code'), i just made like that to shortcut explanation. But i can't remove those layout, it really important for other use. Also in my case, it's not suitable to use recyclerview. Because i am going to display dynamic variation of widgets(probably they has different order). If i do some experiment like remove all AdViews, my scrollview works smoothly. But i can't remove these Adviews for job purpose